# JSF and jasper example

Tags: jsf, jasper-reports

I am new to JSF, I want to integrate JSF with Jasper report. I am generating custom report from server side, that report should display into the UI using JSF components. 
How to do that? Could you please provide the JSF and Jasper Report Simple Program and required libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're talking about HTML reports of JasperReports, your best bet is to forget about the JSF bit at this stage, since this is irrelevant for JasperReports. In turn, JSF also can't do anything sensible with "3rd party" HTML. Just add a HTML `<iframe>` element to the JSF page whose `src` points to the URL of a `HttpServlet` instance which returns the desired HTML report of JasperReports based on request parameters or pathinfo, which you in turn can pass dynamically using EL. E.g.:

```
<iframe width="600" height="400" src="reportservlet?id=${bean.someid}"></iframe>
```

The `HttpServlet` behind the `url-pattern` of `/reportservlet` has just to invoke JasperReports as per its documentation/tutorials, obtain an `InputStream` of it and write it to the `OutputStream` of the `HttpServletResponse` along with a correct set of response headers, at least the `Content-Type` is important.

Answer (score 0):

BalusC suggestion seems good in case you want HTML reports. 
Here is my answer in case you wanted any other format (say PDF)

Make an Ajax request on the servlet to "prepare" the report and store it somewhere then return you the ID of the newly created report.

The response comes back with either success or fail. In case of success you popup a new window with a hypothetical URL and stream the PDF file to it (using the ID you have)

Answer (score 0):

You can download jar from below link

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/d/Downloaddynamicreportscore310jar.htm

Or If you are using maven then just add below dependency to your pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.dynamicreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>dynamicreports-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

XHTML page

```
<h:commandLink id="summary_jasper" actionListener="#{workReportBean.prepareJasperReport()}">
      <p:graphicImage name="/images/jasper.png"  title="Jasper"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

Managed Bean
//Just provide DB_NAME, CREDENTIALS and TABLE_NAME, JASPER report will be created for you

```
public void prepareJasperReport(){
    Map<String, String> columnNameNTypeMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB_NAME", "USER", "PASSWORD");
        ResultSet rsColumns = null;
        DatabaseMetaData meta = connection.getMetaData();
        rsColumns = meta.getColumns(null, null, "TABLE_NAME", null);
        while (rsColumns.next()) {
            columnNameNTypeMap.put(rsColumns.getString("COLUMN_NAME"), rsColumns.getString("TYPE_NAME"));
        }} catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    // a new report
    JasperReportBuilder report = DynamicReports.report();
    // populating new report with TABLE object
    report.setDataSource("select * from TABLE_NAME;", connection);
    // creating COLUMNS // add extra datatypes if your table have ex. long, float etc
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : columnNameNTypeMap.entrySet()){
        if(entry.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("int")){
            report.columns(Columns.column(entry.getKey(), entry.getKey(), DataTypes.integerType()));
        }else if(entry.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("varchar")){
            report.columns(Columns.column(entry.getKey(), entry.getKey(), DataTypes.stringType()));
        }else if(entry.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("bit")){
            report.columns(Columns.column(entry.getKey(), entry.getKey(), DataTypes.booleanType()));
        }else if(entry.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("datetime") || entry.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("date")){
            report.columns(Columns.column(entry.getKey(), entry.getKey(), DataTypes.dateType()));
        }

    }

    report.title(Components.text("Summary Report").setHeight(40)
            .setStyle(DynamicReports.stl.style()
            .setBold(true).setFontSize(16).setForegroundColor(Color.BLUE)
            .setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER, VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE)));

    report.setColumnTitleStyle(DynamicReports.stl.style().setBold(true));
    report.setColumnStyle(DynamicReports.stl.style().setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT));
    report.setHighlightDetailEvenRows(true);
    report.pageFooter(Components.pageXofY());

    try {
        // show the report
        report.show(false);
        // export the report to a pdf file
        //report.toPdf(new FileOutputStream("d://report.pdf"));
    } catch (DRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } /*catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/

}
```